# Grid cell size on raster plot too small, not filling in map/bearly visible (R)

Tags: r, plot, coordinates, raster, spatial

I have a lat/lon coordinated dataset. I've converted the dataset to raster layer using raster::rasterFromXYZ. The dimensions of the raster layer are: 1249, 2551, 3186199 (nrow, ncol, ncell). In checking the spatial extent everything looks fine: -83.13167, -74.62833, 41.70833, 45.87167 (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax).

I've used the rasterFromXYZ function for other locations and datasets are it works fine (for example, last figures below), but when I use it on the dataset below ( a subset of the full dataset described above) the grids are tiny and nearly visible (figure below). The resolution are the same: 0.003333333, 0.003333333  (x, y), for both of the figures.

Does raster layers have maximum ncells they can handle? Or is there a way to increase the grid cell size?

```
df <- structure(list(lon = c(-82.71, -82.63, -82.71, -82.63, -82.54, 
                       -82.71, -82.63, -82.54, -82.46, -82.96, -82.88, -82.79, -82.71, 
                       -82.63, -82.54, -82.46, -82.96, -82.88, -82.79, -82.71, -82.63, 
                       -82.54, -82.46, -82.96, -82.88, -82.79, -82.71, -82.63, -82.54, 
                       -82.46, -82.38, -82.29, -82.21, -82.96, -82.88, -82.79, -82.71, 
                       -82.63, -82.54, -82.46, -82.38, -82.29, -82.21, -82.13, -82.04, 
                       -81.96, -81.88, -82.96, -82.88, -82.79, -82.71, -82.63, -82.54, 
                       -82.46, -82.38, -82.29, -82.21, -82.13, -82.04, -81.96, -81.88, 
                       -81.79, -82.96, -82.88, -82.54, -82.46, -82.38, -82.29, -82.21, 
                       -82.13, -82.04, -81.96, -81.88, -81.79, -81.71, -82.63, -82.54, 
                       -82.46, -82.38, -82.29, -82.21, -82.13, -82.04, -81.96, -81.88, 
                       -81.79, -81.71, -81.63, -82.71, -82.63, -82.54, -82.46, -82.38, 
                       -82.29, -82.21, -82.13, -82.04, -81.96, -81.88, -81.79, -81.71, 
                       -81.63, -81.54, -81.46, -82.54, -82.46, -82.38, -82.29, -82.21, 
                       -82.13, -82.04, -81.96, -81.88, -81.79, -81.71, -81.63, -81.54, 
                       -81.46, -81.38, -82.54, -82.46, -82.38, -82.29, -82.21, -82.13, 
                       -82.04, -81.96, -81.88, -81.79, -81.71, -81.63, -81.54, -81.46, 
                       -81.38, -82.46, -82.38, -82.29, -82.21, -82.13, -82.04, -81.96, 
                       -81.88, -81.79, -81.71, -81.63, -81.54, -81.46, -81.38, -82.46, 
                       -82.38, -82.29, -82.21, -82.13, -82.04, -81.96, -81.88, -81.79, 
                       -81.71, -81.63, -81.54, -81.46, -81.38, -82.46, -82.38, -82.29, 
                       -82.21, -82.13, -82.04, -81.96, -81.88, -81.79, -81.71, -81.63, 
                       -81.54, -81.46, -81.38, -80.71, -80.63, -80.54, -80.46, -80.38, 
                       -80.29, -80.21, -80.13, -80.04, -81.29, -81.21, -81.13, -81.04, 
                       -80.96, -80.88, -80.79, -80.71, -80.63, -80.54, -80.46, -80.38, 
                       -80.29, -80.21, -81.29, -81.21, -81.13, -81.04, -80.96, -80.88, 
                       -80.79, -80.71, -80.63, -80.54, -80.46, -80.38, -80.29, -81.29, 
                       -81.21, -81.13, -81.04, -80.96, -80.88, -80.79, -80.71, -80.63, 
                       -80.54, -80.46, -80.38, -80.29, -80.21, -80.13, -80.04, -79.96, 
                       -79.88, -79.79, -81.29, -81.21, -81.13, -81.04, -80.96, -80.88, 
                       -80.79, -80.71, -80.63, -80.54, -80.46, -80.38, -80.29, -80.21, 
                       -80.13, -80.04, -79.96, -79.88, -79.79, -79.71, -79.63, -79.54, 
                       -79.46, -79.38, -79.29, -79.21, -79.13, -79.04, -78.96, -78.88, 
                       -81.29, -81.21, -81.13, -81.04, -80.96, -80.88, -80.79, -80.71, 
                       -80.63, -80.54, -80.46, -80.38, -80.29, -80.21, -80.13, -80.04, 
                       -79.96, -79.88, -79.79, -79.71, -79.63, -79.54, -79.46, -79.38, 
                       -79.29, -79.21, -79.13, -79.04, -78.96, -78.88), lat = c(41.71, 
                                                                                41.71, 41.79, 41.79, 41.79, 41.87, 41.87, 41.87, 41.87, 41.96, 
                                                                                41.96, 41.96, 41.96, 41.96, 41.96, 41.96, 42.04, 42.04, 42.04, 
                                                                                42.04, 42.04, 42.04, 42.04, 42.12, 42.12, 42.12, 42.12, 42.12, 
                                                                                42.12, 42.12, 42.12, 42.12, 42.12, 42.21, 42.21, 42.21, 42.21, 
                                                                                42.21, 42.21, 42.21, 42.21, 42.21, 42.21, 42.21, 42.21, 42.21, 
                                                                                42.21, 42.29, 42.29, 42.29, 42.29, 42.29, 42.29, 42.29, 42.29, 
                                                                                42.29, 42.29, 42.29, 42.29, 42.29, 42.29, 42.29, 42.37, 42.37, 
                                                                                42.37, 42.37, 42.37, 42.37, 42.37, 42.37, 42.37, 42.37, 42.37, 
                                                                                42.37, 42.37, 42.46, 42.46, 42.46, 42.46, 42.46, 42.46, 42.46, 
                                                                                42.46, 42.46, 42.46, 42.46, 42.46, 42.46, 42.54, 42.54, 42.54, 
                                                                                42.54, 42.54, 42.54, 42.54, 42.54, 42.54, 42.54, 42.54, 42.54, 
                                                                                42.54, 42.54, 42.54, 42.54, 42.62, 42.62, 42.62, 42.62, 42.62, 
                                                                                42.62, 42.62, 42.62, 42.62, 42.62, 42.62, 42.62, 42.62, 42.62, 
                                                                                42.62, 42.71, 42.71, 42.71, 42.71, 42.71, 42.71, 42.71, 42.71, 
                                                                                42.71, 42.71, 42.71, 42.71, 42.71, 42.71, 42.71, 42.79, 42.79, 
                                                                                42.79, 42.79, 42.79, 42.79, 42.79, 42.79, 42.79, 42.79, 42.79, 
                                                                                42.79, 42.79, 42.79, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 
                                                                                42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.96, 
                                                                                42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 
                                                                                42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.54, 42.54, 42.54, 42.54, 42.54, 
                                                                                42.54, 42.54, 42.54, 42.54, 42.62, 42.62, 42.62, 42.62, 42.62, 
                                                                                42.62, 42.62, 42.62, 42.62, 42.62, 42.62, 42.62, 42.62, 42.62, 
                                                                                42.71, 42.71, 42.71, 42.71, 42.71, 42.71, 42.71, 42.71, 42.71, 
                                                                                42.71, 42.71, 42.71, 42.71, 42.79, 42.79, 42.79, 42.79, 42.79, 
                                                                                42.79, 42.79, 42.79, 42.79, 42.79, 42.79, 42.79, 42.79, 42.79, 
                                                                                42.79, 42.79, 42.79, 42.79, 42.79, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 
                                                                                42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 
                                                                                42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 
                                                                                42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.87, 42.96, 
                                                                                42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 
                                                                                42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 
                                                                                42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 42.96, 
                                                                                42.96, 42.96), hist_sum = c(203, 203.5, 192, 197, 194.5, 186, 
                                                                                                            185.5, 189, 189, 188.5, 187.5, 187, 186.5, 186.5, 186.5, 185.5, 
                                                                                                            195, 196.5, 190, 190.5, 187.5, 182, 178, 182.5, 183.5, 183.5, 
                                                                                                            182.5, 178.5, 173, 169.5, 172.5, 172, 169.5, 188.5, 184.5, 184.5, 
                                                                                                            182, 174, 171.5, 169, 165.5, 165.5, 171.5, 171.5, 170.5, 173.5, 
                                                                                                            176, 192, 187.5, 179.5, 174, 170, 166, 164, 164.5, 169, 171.5, 
                                                                                                            173, 171, 171, 173.5, 174.5, 177, 176, 165, 165, 165, 172, 178.5, 
                                                                                                            175.5, 175.5, 179.5, 178, 178, 178.5, 157, 157.5, 160, 165.5, 
                                                                                                            166, 171, 173, 178, 179, 179, 179.5, 186, 187, 145, 154.5, 156.5, 
                                                                                                            159, 163, 164, 166.5, 167, 166, 167, 172, 181.5, 186.5, 189.5, 
                                                                                                            190, 190, 145.5, 159, 160.5, 161, 164.5, 165, 165, 164.5, 167.5, 
                                                                                                            169.5, 175.5, 177.5, 181.5, 188, 188.5, 133, 150, 154, 156, 159, 
                                                                                                            160, 161, 161.5, 165, 168.5, 169.5, 172.5, 177, 186, 188.5, 146.5, 
                                                                                                            152, 154, 158.5, 159, 160.5, 161, 163, 164.5, 167, 170, 174.5, 
                                                                                                            178, 181.5, 142, 148, 154.5, 158.5, 166.5, 163, 159.5, 162.5, 
                                                                                                            162, 165, 168.5, 170.5, 172, 182, 142, 154, 159.5, 160.5, 161.5, 
                                                                                                            157, 155, 161.5, 163.5, 168.5, 171.5, 174.5, 176.5, 181, 182, 
                                                                                                            184, 186, 185.5, 185, 183, 180.5, 183, 181.5, 192.5, 199.5, 198, 
                                                                                                            197.5, 192.5, 189, 187.5, 187, 192, 193.5, 195.5, 194, 188, 188.5, 
                                                                                                            197.5, 201.5, 204, 201.5, 200.5, 196.5, 196.5, 196.5, 194.5, 
                                                                                                            196.5, 204.5, 197.5, 193.5, 192.5, 200.5, 199, 198, 200.5, 206, 
                                                                                                            203.5, 204.5, 201.5, 197.5, 194, 196.5, 197, 193, 186.5, 187, 
                                                                                                            179.5, 175.5, 170.5, 185.5, 187.5, 188.5, 192, 198.5, 209, 210, 
                                                                                                            206.5, 205.5, 205, 197, 191, 193.5, 188.5, 183.5, 184, 181.5, 
                                                                                                            174, 167.5, 166, 168, 167.5, 169.5, 175, 179.5, 180.5, 178.5, 
                                                                                                            183.5, 187, 172, 184, 181, 185, 187, 190, 194, 198.5, 198.5, 
                                                                                                            197, 192.5, 192, 185, 182.5, 178, 174.5, 176.5, 167.5, 165.5, 
                                                                                                            162.5, 161, 163, 164.5, 163.5, 170.5, 179, 180, 179, 180, 176.5, 
                                                                                                            164)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -291L))
```

```
library(raster)

canada_map <- getData("GADM",country="can",level=1)
raster <- rasterFromXYZ(df[,c(1,2,3)])
col_ramp <- colorRampPalette(c("blue", "green", "red"))
cuts_year <- pretty(df[,3], n = 20)
cuts_averages <- pretty(df[,3], n = 20)


plot(raster$hist_sum, breaks = cuts_year, col = col_ramp(25))
# plot(canada_map[9,], add = TRUE)
mtext("Longitude", side = 1, line = 2.1, font = 2, cex = 1)
mtext("Latitude", side = 2, line = 2.6, font = 2, cex = 1)
# abline(v = pretty(df[,1], n = 10), lty = 3, lwd = 0.2, col = "grey75")
# abline(h = pretty(df[,2], n = 10), lty = 3, lwd = 0.2, col = "grey75")
```

Plot output from code above:
[image]
Zoomed into the bottom left, you see the size of the grid cells.
[image]
I used the exact same method on another dataset, although smaller - 14, 47, 658  (nrow, ncol, ncell), and it worked out fine.
[image]